# I am not able to install super-gradients package

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, onnxruntime, yolonas

```
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run
      self.run_command("build")
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xy4b0tkq\onnx_f56fe69240024f2d995c119e7073bfaa\setup.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command("cmake_build")
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\avantika hans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xy4b0tkq\onnx_f56fe69240024f2d995c119e7073bfaa\setup.py", line 209, in run
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_args)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\cmake-3.27.5-windows-x86_64\\bin\\cmake.exe', '-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\include', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\python.exe', '-DBUILD_ONNX_PYTHON=ON', '-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON', '-DONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx', '-DPY_EXT_SUFFIX=.cp311-win_amd64.pyd', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DPY_VERSION=3.11', '-A', 'x64', '-T', 'host=x64', '-DONNX_ML=1', 'C:\\Users\\avantika hans\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xy4b0tkq\\onnx_f56fe69240024f2d995c119e7073bfaa']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for onnx
Running setup.py clean for onnx
Failed to build pycocotools onnx
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycocotools, onnx, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: The backtrace only covers the main process, which has no way of knowing what exactly went wrong. It's likely that whatever went wrong and crashed cmake was printed before that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and recall that the problem was python version. I see you are using 3.11 but Deci only mention [SG support for 3.10](https://github.com/Deci-AI/super-gradients#whats-new).

Try to make an environment with python 3.10 and install. Then it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the installation via `pip` with `venv`:

```
python -m venv env
env\Scripts\activate 
pip install super-gradients
```

Comment: note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for onnx
Failed to build pycocotools onnx
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycocotools, onnx, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pycocotools (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for pycocotools (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycocotools
Failed to build pycocotools
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycocotools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects